# Is there a natural multiplication on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I know that $(\mathbb{R}, +)/(\mathbb{Z}, +)$ makes sense as a quotient group, which gives the circle group. However, $\mathbb{Z}$ is not an ideal in $(\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot)$, so we can't view $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ as a quotient ring, i.e. the normal procedure we might hope to use to get a multiplication on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't result in a ring.

Are there any other common/useful ways to define multiplication on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ that perhaps result in a weaker structure than a ring?

Comment: Is the multiplication $(r+\Bbb Z)\cdot (s+\Bbb Z)=rs+\Bbb Z$ still well-defined? No, as Noah writes. So it is not clear to me how to multiply then.

Comment: @DietrichBurde No: should ${1\over 2}\cdot 0$ be $0$ or ${1\over 2}$?

Comment: Seems worth noting that multiplication on $S^1$ corresponds to addition on $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$. So if you found a multiplication on $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ it would turn $S^1$ into a ring with addition given by multiplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us assume that there is a multiplication $*$ on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ which is distributive over the natural addition.

Let $x\in \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. Then $x$ has finite (additive) order $n$, and thus multiplication by $x$ (say on the left) is a group endomorphism $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ with image included in the subgroup of $n$-torsion of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, which is finite. Since $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a divisible group, this is the zero morphism.

So already, for any $x\in \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, $x*y=0$ for all $y\in \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. With the same reasoning applied to multiplication on the right, $y*x=0$ too.

I think this should show that there is little hope for an interesting multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Even at the level of modules things break immediately. While $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module *(note that as part of the definition of module-ness I require $1\cdot x=x$ so the multiplication is nontrivial)*, there is no way to construe $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ as a $K$-module for any strictly larger subring $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$. It's probably easiest to see this by first considering the case $K=\mathbb{Z}[{1\over 2}]$, where we can reason as follows: $${1\over 2}+{1\over 2}=0\implies\color{red}{2}\cdot{1\over 2}=0\implies\color{red}{1\over 2}\cdot\color{red}{2}\cdot {1\over 2}={1\over 2},$$ but this in turn gives $$\color{red}{1\over 2}\cdot 0={1\over 2}\mbox{ and }\color{red}{1\over 2}\cdot 0=0.$$

---

At this point it's instructive to see exactly where a "naive" approach to defining multiplication breaks down, and for this let's shift back to thinking in terms of rings rather than mere modules. To make things very explicit, I'll now distinguish between e.g. $0$ (a real number) and $[0]_\mathbb{Z}$ (the element of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ corresponding to $0$).

For $x\in\mathbb{R}$, let $\widehat{x}$ be the fractional part of $x$ *(this corresponds to using the "obvious" choice of representatives for the equivalence classes in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$; we could use other choices, but that would just make things less clear)*. Things look rosy for a brief moment: given **any** binary (or higher!) operation $\star$ on $\mathbb{R}$ we get an analogue $\widehat{\star}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $$[x]_\mathbb{Z}\widehat{\star}[y]_\mathbb{Z}=[\widehat{x}\star\widehat{y}]_\mathbb{Z}.$$ For instance, using our above choice of representatives we have $$[{37\over 2}]_\mathbb{Z}\widehat{\cdot}[0]_\mathbb{Z}=[{1\over 2}\cdot 0]_\mathbb{Z}=[0]_\mathbb{Z}.$$ **This is trivially well-defined**, and moreover $\widehat{+}$ is the usual notion of addition on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$; the issue is that algebraic properties of $\mathbb{R}$ will *sometimes-but-not-always*  translate via the $\widehat{?}$-trick to $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Let's first see an example that **works**. Suppose $\star$ is a commutative binary operation on $\mathbb{R}$. Then for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ we get $$[x]_\mathbb{Z}\widehat{\star}[y]_\mathbb{Z}=[\widehat{x}\star \widehat{y}]_\mathbb{Z}\color{green}{=}[\widehat{y}\star\widehat{x}]_\mathbb{Z}=[y]_\mathbb{Z}\widehat{\star}[x]_\mathbb{Z},$$ where the green equality comes from commutativity of $\star$ in the "original" setting $\mathbb{R}$.

Now let's see one that **breaks horribly**, namely *distributivity*. Note that this involves two binary operations at once; to keep things concrete, let's use the standard $+$ and $\cdot$ rather than thinking in terms of arbitrary operations as we did in the previous paragraph. When we try to prove $\widehat{\mbox{distributivity}}$, and no I'm not apologizing for that, things start off well with $$[x]\widehat{\cdot}([y]\widehat{+}[z])=[x]_\mathbb{Z}\widehat{\cdot}([\widehat{y}+\widehat{z}]_\mathbb{Z})=[\widehat{x}\cdot(\widehat{\widehat{y}+\widehat{z}})]_\mathbb{Z}.$$ But this is as far as we can go: the "hatted plus" can't be simplified.

(At this point it's an interesting exercise to see why associativity of $+$ **does** "hattify," given that it seems to run into exactly the same problem.)